# Can we get NFT data from Blockchain Block Data using web3?

Tags: blockchain, analytics, smartcontracts, nft, blockchain.info-api

Hi Blockchain specialist
I have had a query in Blockchain: I am exploring a way to get details of the NFT directly by accessing the Block in the blockchain Node. My first question is can this be achieved without using any third-party API calls. I want to explore Open Source solutions. I am getting started in this technology and I am open to taking valuable suggestions

Comment: web.js or ether.js are open-source SDKs to read blockchain data. They are good for testing and learning, However, they don't provide you infinite access to blockchain data. At some point, your would need 3rd party APIs like Morlais API to speed up reading data from the blockchain. 
https://docs.moralis.io/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can read any data, also NFT, directly from the blockchain. You don't need any third-party or centralized services.

NFT are stored in the form of a JSON in the given contract. I recommend walking through the whole NFT tutorial to understand the whole concept. You can find a very good one at Buildspace: https://buildspace.so/p/mint-nft-collection.